# When I start puppeteer, the window has an empty white border

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

when I start puppeteer, I get a really weird empty border. The whole thing looks like this:
[image]

Is there a way to get the empty border away, or is this normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `defaultViewport: null`,

You can use the default page opened by puppeteer, like this:

```
    async function launchBrowser() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        executablePath: process.env.CHROMIUM_PATH,
        defaultViewport: null,
        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true
    });
    return browser; 
}

const browser = await launchBrowser()
const defaultPages = await browser.pages()
const page = defaultPages[0]
await page.goto('https://www.google.com.my/')
```

Here the window will also be having only one tab and not that empty tab.

Comment: really small improvement, you have to change "defaultpages[0]" to "defaultPages[0]"

Comment: yup. you are right :). Edited the answer.